# WheelDown also sends WheelUp

Tags: autohotkey, mouse

My mouse wheel is busted so i made a ahk script to simulate using my mousewheel.
I also added a keystroke output for troubleshooting purposes.

This has revealed to me that Wheeldown also sends Wheelup.
Any idea what could cause this to happen and how to fix it?

Loaded script:

[image]

result:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/FLqotHG.png]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That script of yours doesn't reveal anything about the wheel of your mouse. Without a [return](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Return.htm#ExBasic) at the end of a hotkey subroutine the script jumps to the next line and executes the next hotkey subroutine.

Try this

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
#InstallKeybdHook
#InstallMouseHook

WheelDown::KeyHistory
WheelUp::KeyHistory
```

[KeyHistory](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/KeyHistory.htm) displays the most recent keyboard and mouse button events. This way you can see whether the mouse wheel is malfunctioning.

Comment: Thanks! Hadn't used ahk in a while and I forgot a return was necessary